# Remove certain part of expression

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a macro variable as follows

```
%let var=a b(ref='aaa') c d(ref='zzz');
```

I want to remove everything enclosed in parentheses to get the result `a b c d`. How should I go about doing this in an elegant way?

Comment: I don't think there is elegant way doing this. You should find openinig parenthesis and ending one then use other SAS functions for operating on string like `substr` or `tranwrd` function to replace it. Did you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions can solve this, take a look at this:

```
%let var=a b(ref='aaa') c d(ref='zzz');
data _null_;
  x=prxchange("s/\([^)]*\)//",-1,"&var");
  put x=;
run;
```

The log will display:

```
x=a b c d
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for! For completeness, to be able to use the answer inside a macro I had to modify it to: `%sysfunc(prxchange(%str(s/\%([^%)]*\%)//),-1,"&var"));`